# AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that will log the names of people who use a command. The bot would give an error when there was unicode in a name it tried to log, so to fix that, I changed the txt encoding to  UTF-8, and put this in the code:

```
 .encode("utf-8")
```

This is the full line of code:

```
logmsg=str(message.author)+" has used the 'hello' command"
    logs=str(open("pylogs.txt","a").encode("utf-8"))
    logs.write(logmsg+"\n")
    logs.close()
    print(logmsg)
```

But whenever it tries to log someone with unicode in their name, I get this:

```
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I'm stumped...

Comment: You can't call `encode` on a file. And, while you _can_ call `str(…)` on a file, I don't think you want to (and you certainly won't be able to call `write` on the result). I'm not sure exactly what you were trying to do there, but my best guess is `logs = open("pylogs.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8")`?

Comment: Ill try it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!